# Scheduling multiple batch classes from postinstall script of managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, batch, schedulebatch, postinstall

I know we can schedule batch classes from post install scripts, but need to confirm this in my scenario. 
I have to schedule two batch classes which will update the data of two objects and also insert attachments during upgrade of managed package. During update, multiple triggers will execute. 
Post install script uses ghost user. Will this user be able to access the records and perform DML through dependent classes (with sharing). Also, I am using SoC pattern in dependent classes.

Comment: Yes, you can perform the dml in post Install script. I have tried in one of my managed package

Comment: Yes we can do that. But keeping my dependent classes as with sharing, will create issue ? and also we have SoC in dependent classes.